# Pass variables from properties file into distributionManagement tag in pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

So I have something like:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>read-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>${user.home}/build.properties</file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and I have `distributionManagement` like:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>local-repo</id>
        <url>file:///${deploy.dir}/${project.artifactId}</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

I don't have a remote repository, that is why I am doing it using `file:///`

`${deploy.dir}` is a property from the `build.properties` file and it will not take the value for that property.
Why?

Comment: If you run your maven command with `-Ddeploy.dir=<yourDirectoryHere>` does it work as expected?

Comment: @user944849,it works that way,  but I wanted to do this from the pom.xml

Comment: Right.  I was pretty sure that `<distributionManagement>` was interpolated when the POM was first loaded and you confirmed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark's answer is probably the way to go, and is what I'm doing to switch between our production and test instances of our remote repository. [Per a discussion I found](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Lifecycle-phase-in-which-the-url-for-distributionManagement-snapshotRepository-is-calculated-td5673069.html) it sounds like you can load properties for use in later plugin configurations, but core maven model elements like `<distributionManagement>` only have properties interpreted on initial load of the POM.

(Moving comment to answer per OP request.)

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest using build profiles to manage multiple distribution targets. For example:

```
<profiles>
   <profile>
      <id>repo1</id>
      <distributionManagement>
         <repository>
            <id>repo1-release</id>
            <url>http://.......</url>
         </repository>
      </distributionManagement>
   </profile>

   <profile>
      <id>repo2</id>
      <distributionManagement>
         <repository>
            <id>repo2-release</id>
            <url>http://.......</url>
         </repository>
      </distributionManagement>
   </profile>
   ..
</profiles>
```

When calling the deploy goal you can choose the destination by activating the profile:

```
mvn -Prepo1 clean deploy
```

Comment: Mark's answer is probably the way to go, and is what I'm doing to switch between our production and test instances of our remote repository.  [Per a discussion I found](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Lifecycle-phase-in-which-the-url-for-distributionManagement-snapshotRepository-is-calculated-td5673069.html) it sounds like you can load properties for use in later plugin configurations, but core maven model elements like `<distributionManagement>` only have properties interpreted on initial load of the POM.

Comment: @user944849, that answered my question, thanks :). You can put an answer with your comment and I'll mark it as accepted answer.