# read Maven variable from properties file using profile

Tags: maven, configure

I want to read a maven variable for configure a build plugin from a properties file. It's not needed in and further project files e.g. context files.

1) made a profile (it works, can use mvn ... -P private)

```
<profile>
 <id>private</id>
  <properties>
   <env>private</env>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

2) created the filter file with this content (it works)
    foo.path=/home/foo/path

3) try to configure the plugin (does not work)

```
<build>
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${foo-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
     <!--<fooPath>home/foo/path></fooPath> that works -->
     <fooPath>${foo.path}</fooPath> <!--works not -->
    </configuration>
...
</build>
```

Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

The name of your property is 'env' but you don't use env anywhere in your configuration.

Comment: env is for profile: mvn -P private or further mvn -P default. The filter file is called filter-private.properties. It's ok, I can start the several profiles.

Answer (score 0):

When Maven docs mention "filter files" they usually mean a file used when processing resources (i.e. copying resources from `/src/main/resources` to `target/classes`).  As far as I know the properties in those files aren't used for plugin configuration out-of-the-box.  I have used the Codehaus [properties-maven-plugin:read-project-properties](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/read-project-properties-mojo.html) goal do do what you are attempting. Make sure you bind the goal to the lifecycle before any plugins that need the properties for config.

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10686445/944849); you may load properties used to configure other plugins, but not to configure core Maven project elements.