# Reading properties file values into pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-2, dependency-properties, maven-plugin, pom.xml

I've tried and follow this solution
[How to read an external properties file in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849389/how-to-read-an-external-properties-file-in-maven)
but with no luck.

I would like to read an absolute path(/home/tomcat/lib) from a properties file(which is in the same location as pom.xml) and set the value in the pom.xml

project.properties file contains:

myTomCat.lib.location=/home/tomcat/lib

pom.xml configuration contains:

```
<properties>
    <envTomcatLib>${myTomCat.lib.location}</envTomcatLib>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
           <artifactId>MyJar</artifactId>
       <groupId>MyJar</groupId>
       <scope>system</scope>
       <version>1.0</version>
       <systemPath>/${envTomcatLib}/MyJar.jar</systemPath>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <files>
            <file>${basedir}/project.properties</file>
          </files>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

The problem is either at eclipse compile time or running "mvn install" that the placeholder ${envTomcatLib}/MyJar.jar, can't get resolved to /home/tomcat/lib/MyJar.jar and remains  ${envTomcatLib}/MyJar.jar.

Can someone please assist?

Thanks

Comment: Properties can be set in the Maven settings files. See the doco on Maven build profiles. Additionally using a system scope is a bad idea, leads to unstable and difficult to port builds.

Answer (score 1):

Values in the `<properties>` section are assigned when the POM is initially loaded.  The `properties-maven-plugin` only affects plugin executions that come after the point where the properties were loaded.  More detail in a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10686445/944849) I provided.

BTW, the [Maven Reference Book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html) has this to say about system scope: "Note that this scope is not recommended (you should always try to reference dependencies in a public or custom Maven repository)."

Answer (score 0):

You may need to remove `"/"` before `/${envTomcatLib}/MyJar.jar`  or  give property value as `home/tomcat/lib` instead of `/home/tomcat/lib`. It may be the reason for not able to resolve your location.